# Setup ufw and HTTP using certbot and I can no longer use SFTP

Tags: nginx, https, sftp, digital-ocean, ufw

I setup UFW and HTTPS on my digitalocean droplet and I can no longer SFTP into my box. Are there extra steps to enable SFTP into the box?

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04#step-4-%E2%80%93-managing-the-nginx-process

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-let-s-encrypt-with-nginx-server-blocks-on-ubuntu-16-04#prerequisites

```
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that SFTP runs on the SSH port, you could be in trouble. If you can not access your server in any way, then it's probably for the best to reset it since there will be no real other way to gain access to your server again.

Anyhow, if you can connect to your server and update the firewall (execute with `sudo` if necessary), execute the following 2 commands if you have a static IP:

```
ufw allow from [YOUR IP] to any port 22 
ufw reload
```

Otherwise, it is recommended to use a different port for SSH (http://www.linuxlookup.com/howto/change_default_ssh_port). The commands to execute here would be the following:

```
ufw allow [CUSTOM SSH PORT]
ufw reload
```

Also, if you are not yet using a key for your SSH login, take a look at the follwing page: https://www.ssh.com/ssh/key/ . Since it will greatly improve the overall security of your server.

Comment: Thanks, it was a firewall issue. I will look into setting up the ssh key as well.